# Get a list of inventory hostnames

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

```
host1: abc
host2: xyz
```

host1 and host2 are listed under test-hosts

```
[test-hosts]
abc
xyz
```

When i debug for inventory_hostnames, i see them like below

```
    > TASK [debug inventory_hostname]
    > ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************* 
ok: [abc] => {
    >     "inventory_hostname": "abc" } 
ok: [xyz] => {
    >     "inventory_hostname": "xyz" }
```

Is there any way we can gather inventory_hostname's like a list by assigning it to a variable.

Expected result:

```
exp_result: [abc, xyz]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groups['test-hosts']` to get those hosts as a list.

For example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        host_list: "{{ groups['test-hosts'] }}"
    - debug:
        msg:  "{{host_list}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the variable `inventory_hostnames` if you want to select multiple groups or exclude groups with [patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html).

In these examples, we're selecting all hosts except ones in the www group.

Saving the list of hosts as a variable for a task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: hostnames
  vars:
    hostnames: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'all:!www') }}"
```

You can also use the [lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/inventory_hostnames_lookup.html) to loop over the hosts that match the pattern. From the docs:

```yaml
- name: show all the hosts matching the pattern, i.e. all but the group www
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_inventory_hostnames:
    - all:!www
```